# MySQL Get rows that do not match with certain conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

It seems simple in my head but I am at a loss for getting the results I need.

My table

```
id, code, type
 1  1111   1
 2  1111   2
 3  1222   1 <--- This one
 4  1333   1
 5  1333   2
 6  1444   3 <--- Different type then the others
```

I want the output of the one that doesn't have a matching code with type 2 but only look for ones with type 1 or type 2 (if that makes sense)

```
id, code, type
 3  1222   1
```

NOTE: I have over 1 million records to query so I need something fast.

My [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/211c5/4)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain differently! Try explaining to a friend until they at least understand what you're asking then come back and edit your question

Comment: Whoops fixed that type I meant the one without matching code and type 2 so id 3.

Comment: Do you *only* want type 1 codes for which there is no matching type 2 (as per your example), or do you also want type 2 codes for which there is no matching type 1?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/211c5/15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM codes NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   code
  FROM     codes
  WHERE    type IN (1,2)
  GROUP BY code
  HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT type) = 1
) t
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/211c5/11/0).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `not exists`:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM codes c
WHERE c.type = 1 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from codes c2
                  where c2.code = c.code and
                        c2.type = 2
                 )
```